# LINQ expression working in VS2012 not working in VS2015

Tags: vb.net, linq, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I have a complex query made in LINQ that is working just fine in a debugging environment in Visual Studio 2012. When I execute the same query with the same database using Visual Studio 2015 it throws the following exception:

> Message: No se puede convertir el tipo
>   'System.Nullable`1[[System.Decimal, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' al tipo
>   'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities solo admite la conversión de tipos
>   de enumeración o primitivos de EDM.

Google translation to English:

> Cannot convert type 'System.Nullable`1 [[System.Decimal, mscorlib, Version = 4.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b77a5c561934e089]] to type' System.Object '. LINQ to Entities only supports the conversion of enumeration types or EDM primitives.

Here is the expression. It's pretty complex to explain but maybe there's something wrong that can be seen easily:

```
 Dim dsRiesgoDatosParte1 = listRiesgoEntities _
                    .Select(Function(r) New With {
                        .Id = r.IdRiesgo,
                        .Nombre = r.Nombre,
                        .Descripcion = r.Descripcion,
                        .Costo = r.Costo,
                        .CategoriaRiesgoNivel1 = r.IdCategoriaRiesgo1,
                        .CategoriaRiesgoNivel2 = r.IdCategoriaRiesgo2,
                        .CategoriaRiesgoNivel3 = r.IdCategoriaRiesgo3,
                        .IdNivelDatos = r.IdNivelDatos,
                        .IdOrganigrama = r.IdOrganigrama,
                        .Ponderacion = r.Ponderacion,
                        .Activo = r.Activo,
                        .Completo = r.Completo,
                        .ModificadaPorUsuarioControles = r.ModificadaPorUsuarioControles,
                        .ModificadaPorUsuarioTratamientos = r.ModificadaPorUsuarioTratamientos,
                        .Comentario = r.Comentario,
                        .ValidacionRiesgo = If(r.ValidacionRiesgo IsNot Nothing, r.ValidacionRiesgo, 0),
                        .ValoracionGlobalControlesValor = If(r.ValoracionControles > 0, r.ValoracionControles, CType(Nothing, String)),
                        .VariablesValoracionGlobalControl = r.DS_RiesgoVariablesValoracionGlobalControl _
                            .Where(Function(i) r.ValoracionControles > 0) _
                            .Select(Function(i) New With {
                                .IdRiesgo = i.IdRiesgo,
                                .IdVariableConfiguracion = i.IdVariableConfiguracion,
                                .tmpIdItem = If(i.IdVariableListaItem IsNot Nothing, i.IdVariableListaItem, -1),
                                .Valor = CType(i.Valor, String)
                            }),
                        .ValoracionGlobalTratamientosValor = If(r.ValoracionTratamientos > 0, r.ValoracionTratamientos, CType(Nothing, String)),
                        .VariablesValoracionGlobalTratamiento = r.DS_RiesgoVariablesValoracionGlobalTratamiento _
                            .Where(Function(i) r.ValoracionTratamientos > 0) _
                            .Select(Function(i) New With {
                                .IdRiesgo = i.IdRiesgo,
                                .IdVariableConfiguracion = i.IdVariableConfiguracion,
                                .tmpIdItem = If(i.IdVariableListaItem IsNot Nothing, i.IdVariableListaItem, 0),
                                .Valor = CType(i.Valor, String)
                            }),
                        .tmpArchivos = r.DS_Archivo.Select(Function(a) New DTOArchivo With {
                            .Id = a.IdArchivo,
                            .Nombre = a.Nombre
                        }),
                        .tmpResponsables = r.DS_Usuarios.Select(Function(u) New DTOResponsable With {
                            .Login = u.USR_Login
                        }),
                        .tmpControlesDatos = r.DS_ControlDato.Select(Function(c) New With {
                            .Id = c.IdControlDato,
                            .Nombre = c.Nombre,
                            .IdVariableConfiguracion = c.IdVariableConfiguracion,
                            .Comentario = c.Comentario,
                            .CostoAnual = c.CostoAnual,
                            .Ponderacion = c.Ponderacion,
                            .ModificadaPorUsuario = c.ModificadaPorUsuario,
                            .Valor = CType(c.Valor, String),
                            .tmpValor = c.Valor,
                            .TiposControles = c.DS_TipoControl.Select(Function(tc) New DTOTipoControl With {
                                .Id = tc.IdTipoControl,
                                .Nombre = tc.Nombre
                            })
                        }),
                        .NivelDato = New DTONivelDato With {
                            .Id = r.DS_NivelDatosFijo.IdNivelDato,
                            .Nombre = r.DS_NivelDatosFijo.Nombre,
                            .Ponderacion = r.DS_NivelDatosFijo.Ponderacion,
                            .IdNivelConfiguracion = r.DS_NivelDatosFijo.IdNivelConfiguracion,
                            .IdNivelPadre = r.DS_NivelDatosFijo.IdNivelPadre,
                            .IdEmpresa = r.DS_NivelDatosFijo.IdEmpresa,
                            .Activo = r.DS_NivelDatosFijo.Activo
                        }
                    }) _
                    .AsEnumerable
```

I tried to split the Select in several parts but couldn't find the problem. Also the exception is thrown when I join the result of the previous query, here's the inspection of `dsRiesgosDatosParte1`:

[image]

As I said, it's working just fine in VS2012 but not in VS2015 so there must be something new in LINQ.

The question is, what has changed in LINQ from VS2012 to VS2015 that could affect the result of the execution? I can't find anywhere why this could happend.

Comment: Visual Studio is just an IDE. The IDE doesn't control how LINQ queries work. Even if the error is caused by some changes to LINQ, you need to check the version of asp.net that you are using in VS2015 as opposed to VS2012. If your assumption is true, then changing the version of asp.net in your VS2015 project so it matches the version in VS2012 should fix the issue. Try that and let us know what happens.

Comment: first of all - @DiegoS - translate the exception! :) - i understood only that you have null somewhere

Comment: Do you have a variable of type Nullable(Of Decimal) somewhere in there?